# Does $Q(x) =1 -x + \frac{x^2}{2}- \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} -\frac{x^5}{5} +\frac{x^6}{6}$ have any real zeros?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does $Q(x) =1 -x + \frac{x^2}{2}- \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^4}{4} -\frac{x^5}{5} +\frac{x^6}{6}$ have any real zeros?

\begin{align}
Q'(x) &= -1 + x -x^2 + x^3 -x^4 + x^5 \\
&= -(1-x+x^2)+x^3(1-x+x^2)\\
&=(x^3-1)(x^2-x+1)\\
&=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).
\end{align}

If we set $Q'(x)$ equal to zero, then I get a real critical point of $x=1$. I also get complex critical points from $(x^2 -x +1)$. Since I'm asked if $Q(x)$ has any real roots, should I still plug in the complex critical points into $Q(x)$?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ajsfiiquze. No it doesn't have any zeros. You can argue the case like this: You can argue that $x=1$ is a minimum of $Q$ and when you plug it in $Q(1)>0$ so you can't have any zeros. I think you can use the $Q''(1)=3>0$ to argue that $Q(1)$ is a min.

Comment: You actually get complex critical points from $(1-x^3)$ as well. No, you should not plug in those values because the complex points don't fall in your domain.

Comment: Critical points in this case, don't include roots...I mean if you are asked to find roots, you don't consider critical points. A root for f(x) is a value for x where f(x) becomes zero. Critical points often refer to x values in the domain of f where there is a max. or min. (all these definitions are not exact).

Comment: Are you sure your expansion is the polynomial you say it is? How did you get it the $-(1-x^3)(x^2-x+1)$?

Comment: @NoChance Just expand two first terms $Q'(x)$ from OP.

Comment: @user376343, at first read, I was under the impression the OP meant an infinite series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The derivative has a single real root, namely $1$. The other *two* factors never vanish on $\mathbb{R}$ (and they are actually everywhere positive).

So we have $Q'(x)<0$ for $x<1$ and $Q'(x)>0$ for $x>1$. This implies $1$ is an absolute minimum for $Q(x)$. Note that the limits of $Q$ at $-\infty$ and $\infty$ are both $\infty$, so the absolute minimum must exist.

Since
$$
Q(1)=1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}=\frac{30-20+15-12+10}{60}=\frac{23}{60}>0
$$
we can conclude that $Q(x)>0$ for every $x$.

The complex roots of $Q'$ play no role in this problem, which is about finding the (real) intervals in which $Q$ is monotonic.

Comment: I was wondering what exactly is meant by "the other two factors (complex roots) never vanish on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @K.M The factors are $x-1$, $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$; one of them has a real root, the other two don't. I fixed a bit your algebra.

Answer (score 2):

egreg's answer already resolves the problem, but here's a fun one: recall the maclaurin series for $\ln(x+1)$:
$$\ln(x+1)=x-\frac12x^2+\frac13x^3-\frac14x^4+\cdots=-(Q(x)-1)+O(x^7).$$
This expansion is only valid when the series converges, of course. In that range,
$$Q(x)=-\ln(x+1)+O(x^7)+1.$$
As $x\to-1$ (here, the series expansion works), $\ln(x+1)$ grows much quicker than $x^7$, so no zeroes there. You can check from the original expression of $Q$ that there are no zeros as $x\to\infty$ as well. Of course this is just heuristics, but you can rigorously check this by finding the critical points.

Comment: Is $O(x^7)$ supposed to be the error?

Comment: @K.M what do you mean? It's the "extra trailing terms" that the series expansion for $\ln(1+x)$ has compared to $Q(x)$.

Comment: This expansion of $ln (x+1)$ is correct near $1$, specifically in [-1,1) only, it is not for all values of $x$.

Comment: @NoChance Yes of course you're right, that's the radius of convergence for the series. Edited to reflect that.